# How to run a program (a binary executable) inside awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to loop through rows in a text file and run `ffmpeg` with the field values as parameters. This is the code I tried:

```
awk -F, '{ffmpeg $1 -ss $2 -to $3 $4}' times.txt
```

and here's the content for `times.txt`

```
TheArtofSupporting.mkv,00:11:54,00:13:33,everyone is fighting a battle.mp4
```

But the output is empty. Probably I just assumed that `awk` can run a command inside, but if this is not possible what should I do to achieve my goal. Perhaps I can output the commands into a bash file, or pipe the output by `print` into `sh` ?

Comment: Try: `awk -F, '{printf "ffmpeg %s -ss %s -to %s \47%s\47\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' times.txt | sh` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` has a `system` function:

```
awk -F, '{system("ffmpeg "$1" -ss "$2" -to "$3" "$4)}' times.txt
```

This, like any thing that tries to construct a shell command from possibly untrusted input, should be considered fragile.

Comment: Good point about the whole thing being fragile. Could you point to any resources to know about bash scripting security. Because sometimes these cases are unavoidable. For example for this case, I can perhaps validate this using a regex or something in another pipe.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I figured after asking the question and dwelling on my last comment:

```
awk -F, '{print "ffmpeg -i " $1 " -ss " $2 " -to " $3 " " $4}' times.txt | sh
```